# How do I install Maple?

Tags: software-installation

I am new to Ubuntu and I was wondering if anyone could show me a tutorial or actually show me how to install software, for example Maple software or things like that.

Comment: Have you gone through this link https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Maple

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maple is not free software, see [UbuntuScience](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuScience) for alternatives.

This guide will take you through the steps of installing Maple9.5 or Maple10 in Ubuntu. We will install Maple and create symlinks to the executables.

This may also help troubleshooting installation of maple 16 under ubuntu 12.10.

**Installation**

First, create a directory in /opt for Maple. If you are installing Maple 10, you probably want to call this /opt/maple10 instead. If you do, remember to use the appropriate path for the rest of the commands in this guide.

```
sudo mkdir -p /opt/maple9.5
```

Now, put your Maple 9.5 or Maple 10 cd into your cdrom. It should then be mounted to /media/cdrom. Maple includes a nice installer script for us that we can run:

```
sudo sh /media/cdrom/installMapleLinuxSU
```

We have to run the installer through sh since cdrom's are mounted noexec by default.

Follow the instructions in the Maple installer and choose /opt/maple9.5 as the install directory.

**Symbolic Links**

Now so that we can just type maple to start Maple or xmaple to start the graphical version, we need to create symbolic links somewhere in your $PATH. We will be using /usr/local/bin which is reserved for local installations:

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/bin
sudo ln -s /opt/maple9.5/bin/{x,}maple /usr/local/bin
```

[source here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Maple) together with troubleshooting in case anything goes wrong.

Comment: Why not consider ``maxima`` which is in the official Ubuntu repository. 
 This is port of the parent of Maple and Mathematica: Macsyma.  I use it regularly and it's good.  Not glitzy, but it depends on what you need.