# How to install Maple10 in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: software-installation

I have recently started using Ubuntu. I downloaded from my university the Maple software. I have in my downloads folder a file called

```
Maple2020.1LinuxX64Installer.run
```

and I also have a password provided to me by mu university. When I double-click the above file, I get the message

```
Could not display "Maple2020.1LinuxX64Installer.run"
There is no application installed for "executable" files. 
Do you want to search for an application to open this file?
```

Then I click to choose yes, and I get the following message

```
Unfortunately, the application/x-executable file format you were searching could not be found. Please see this website for more information.
```

When I click the [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/) there is a nice explanation in general terms but I did not find it very helpful. I was wondering if someone could offer some advice and help so I can complete the installation and use Maple.

Doing a quick search I found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/274397/how-do-i-install-maple) which was very clear. I tried these commands on the temrinal but nothing happened. Below you can see a screen-shot

[image]

Comment: Is this software compatible with Ubuntu?  Did you make the file executable (`chmod +x filename`)?  Do you need to use `sudo`?  Does the software developer provide instructions to install the software?  Double clicking a downloaded file is not how you generally install software on Ubuntu, and when it *is* possible, it's usually the *worst* way (ie a .deb file).

Comment: And those commands you are running are specific to the software having been provided on an optical disk. There's no disk so that's why you can't open. Look at the path of the command you are executing..

Comment: @Nmath according to the university's site it is compatible with Ubuntu. also, in this link https://askubuntu.com/questions/274397/how-do-i-install-maple they talk about maple10. I was not aware of this command chmod +x filename that you suggested

Comment: @user535733 Actually I mainly use Mathematica for my projects. For very specific differential equations I would like to see if Maple is able to provide an analytic solution. It has happened in the past and there are explicit examples. So, using Maple10 is just me. Nobody asked me to do anything. My advisor for example is neither using ubuntu nor maple

Comment: That's how you change a file permission to be *executable* using the command line. chmod = change permissions; +x = make executable.  The command to execute a file would be `./filename` (from the same directory). Use sudo if the script needs elevated permissions.  This appears to be non-free software that costs at least $200 USD. Is this file a legitimate distribution of this software?  If not, you probably shouldn't run it

Comment: @Nmath yes, I know it is not free. I got it from my university's website. They also provided a code for the authentication procedure. Everything appears to be legit

Comment: If you still can't install after 1) making it executable; 2) executing the correct path; and 3) using sudo if required-- then contact your university for instructions on how to install the software on Ubuntu

Comment: @Nmath thanks for the tips. and for explaining the command and the logic!